# Move labeled emails from Gmail to .pst

Tags: gmail

I have labelled a few hunderd emails in my Gmail. I would like to connect to my Gmail from Outlook and move all the labelled emails to a `.pst` file. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, the easiest way is to use the **IMAP** functionality of Gmail.

1. Enable IMAP on Gmail
2. Configure Outlook on your computer to handle your Gmail account ([see Google Help](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=ts.cs&ts=1668960&rd=1))
3. Sync your mailboxes. Gmail will create a folder for each label
4. Create a new Outlook `PST`
5. Move (or Copy) all the mails you want (from the folder of the wanted label) to your `.PST`

Comment: JMax, the solutions provided by you is fantastic. but it's kinda slow the outlook on imap. do you have any other suggestions how to export out from gmail server to pst other than using outlook imap or pop3?