# Exporting Gmail to local Outlook PST

Tags: gmail, outlook, imap, pop3

I need to export out emails from Gmail to an Outlook PST file and it seems slow using [this method](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19872/move-labeled-emails-from-gmail-to-pst)—Outlook and IMAP/POP3 are kinda slow on archiving.

Is there any other method than going through POP3 or IMAP?

Comment: method supplied by JMax
http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19872/move-labeled-emails-from-gmail-to-pst

Answer (score 1):

POP3 is not possible because, I think, it doesn't sync labels.

The only other thing is to setup Outlook to only sync specific labels (with IMAP).

Possibly another mail client (like [Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) or [Evolution](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/)) would perform better?

Answer (score 1):

Use Gmail Takeout:

https://www.google.com/settings/takeout

This will leave you with an mbox file. Use Aid4Mail to convert that to a .PST:

http://www.aid4mail.com

Comment: There are offline solutions, too...

Answer (score 1):

I am quite late to respond the thread. Recently I did the same task which I am going to share.

You can backup Gmail account data by using the free [Google takeout](https://www.google.com/settings/takeout) tool. But it will create .mbox file for backed up emails which cannot be open or imported directly into MS Outlook. For that you need to convert MBOX file to PST format using a reliable tool available here: http://www.mboxpst.com

**Note**: The above method is quite lengthy and time consuming. So I will suggest you to configure your Gmail account with MS Outlook and download folders/messages into PST format by using free POP3 mail server.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]! I made some minor edits to your post: Removed the quotation formatting (which we use only for quoting), and added a link to Google takeout.

Answer (score -1):

There, I found one more solution that is **SysTools Gmail Backup Tool**

This helps user To backup Gmail mailbox items into the various format such as EML, PST, MBOX, MSG & EMLX.

Ref:- http://www.zdnet.com/article/ultimate-guide-to-gmail-backup/

I just found this solution in above ref. link. Request to try the demo before purchasing.

Comment: If you are affiliated with the product, please disclose this in your answer.

Comment: Hi, @jonsca, I have nothing to do with this product. If you are not sure about this just google it. I found the above URL while I was searching for this solution. And in the ref. URL I only find the single product that backup Gmail to multiple formats. Sorry if you get it in a wrong way I was just trying to answer. It will be great if you remove your downvote

Comment: Not a problem, it's okay if you are not affiliated, no need to do anything further.  It was not my downvote, that was a system-imposed downvote due to a "low quality" flag.